# Can't start android default music player with startacrtivity

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to make android default music player start to play. I used this code to do that:

```
if (((AudioManager) context
    .getSystemService(context.AUDIO_SERVICE)).isMusicActive()) {
            // pause
            Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
            i.putExtra("command", "pause");
            context.sendBroadcast(i);
} else {
        // play
        Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
        i.putExtra("command", "play");
        context.sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

It works fine when music player app is running in foreground or background, otherwise not.

So I used this in else statement to start it:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC");
inintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(in);
```

But it doesn't work and app crashes. Am i need to use permision to do that? If yes, what permision? If no, what's the problem?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
D/AudioManager(20102): isMusicActive()? --> false
W/CpuWake (  185): >>acquireCpuPerfWakeLock!
W/CpuWake (  185): <<acquireCpuPerfWakeLock!
I/ActivityManager(  185): START intent from pid 20102
W/System.err(20102): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent 
{ act=android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC flg=0x10000000 }
```

Edit: Question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved problem:

```
i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Uri u = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,"1");
context.startActivity(i);
```

Also it's not dependent on music player's package name and works on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for api below 15

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MUSIC_PLAYER");
startActivity(intent);
```

and later use `android.intent.category.APP_MUSIC.`

Try this, `com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity`

where `com.android.music` is the package name of deafult player in my device `ICS 4.0.4`

Comment: Didn't work, app still crashes when it tries to start music player.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace

Comment: Yes I did, same result.

Comment: I tried that with `com.htc.music`. Caused `null pointer exception`